# Диалоги между пользователями

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Необходимо реализовать систему диалогов между пользователями (php + mysql), на подобие той которfя используется в вконтакте. Меня интересует структура БД.
Со структурой для 2 пользователей все понятно:

Таблица users:

```
id | username
```

Таблица messages:

```
id | user_from | user_to | text | date
```

Но как быть со структурой БД для диалогов с неограниченным количеством пользователей. 
Например к своей переписки с одним пользователем я хочу добавить еще скажем троих ?

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Таблица messages:

```
id | user_from | user_to | text | date | room
```

Таблица room:

```
id | name | founder
```

То есть нужно просто создать комнату к каждой переписке и добавлять туда пользователей.

Comment: тогда: id | user_from | user_to | text | date | room_id

Comment: Зачем нужен `user_to`? Сообщение пишется не кому-то конкретному, а просто «в комнату».

Comment: Ну, допустим, для того, чтобы сделать приват или просто адресацию)

Comment: @Jeix, приват - это комната из двух юзеров. Адресация - это айди комнаты.

Comment: @Fike, Создавать каждый раз комнату для того, чтобы написать в приват одно сообщение - бред. Мало ли, вдруг пользователю срочно нужно будет написать в приват, находясь с данным пользователей в одной групповой комнате.  
Под адресацией я имел в виду, например: user1 to user2 и т.д, чтобы было видно кому адресовано данное сообщение :)

Comment: а зачем **user**_to и room ? почему не просто to где to - универсальный id комнаты или юзера...

Comment: @Jeix, создавать две сущности под одно и то же - это бред.

Answer (score 1):

Как раз занимаюсь подобной темой. Тут все зависит от нескольких факторов. Если сообщения нужно удалять (помечать как удаленные, физически лучше удалять по крону), то необходимо держать как минимум копию для собеседников. То есть сообщение, к примеру, в таблице messages, а в таблице, к примеру, messages_to_users - id сообщения и его статус - для каждого из собеседников. Если один собеседник удалит у себя сообщение, то оно останется у других. В качестве примера реализации могу посоветовать структуру как по
[этой ссылке](http://xdan.ru/Sistema-dialogov-na-php-kak-v-v-kontakte.html)

Answer (score 0):

Я вот тоже сижу и думаю над этой задачей.
Мне пришло в голову вот что:
4 таблицы:

```
users - id | name

messages - id | text | fromUserId | roomId

rooms - id

users_room - userId | roomId
```

Когда один пользователь пишет другому то создается комната, в которую можно добавлять сколько угодно пользователей (добавляем поле в таблицу users_room).
Основной вопрос в том каким самым легким запросом можно узнать есть ли уже комната у этих двух пользователей, когда один пишет другому приватное сообщение.
Вот тут я предлагаю такой вариант запроса:

```
SELECT dialogId FROM dialogs_users WHERE dialogId IN 
    (SELECT dialogId FROM dialogs_users WHERE dialogId IN 
        (SELECT dialogId FROM dialogs_users WHERE userId=MyLogedUserId)
    AND userId=MessageToUserId GROUP BY dialogId)
GROUP BY dialogId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

где:
MyLogedUserId - id нашего авторизованного пользователя (берем из сессии)
MessageToUserId - id пользователя, которому отсылаем сообщение

Поясню:

```
SELECT dialogId FROM dialogs_users WHERE userId=MyLogedUserId`
```

Выбираем все комнаты нашего пользователя

```
SELECT dialogId FROM dialogs_users WHERE dialogId IN (SELECT dialogId FROM dialogs_users WHERE userId=MyLogedUserId) AND userId=MessageToUserId GROUP BY dialogId
```

Выбираем все общие комнаты нашего пользователя с тем, которому мы отсылаем сообщение

Ну и весь запрос целиком выбирает нам общие комнаты наших двух пользователей, количество людей в которых равно 2.

Если такая комната есть, то запрос вернет ее id, если нет - нужно ее создать, добавить туда этих двух пользователей а затем сообщение.

Может кто-то придумает лучше запрос? Пишите.

Comment: Это ужасный вариант! При таком подходе никогда не будут использоваться индексы, даже если они есть. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, что будет, если в таблице dialogs_users будет 100 записей (не так уж и много)? Будет обработано 1 000 000 строк, т.к. 2 подзапроса.

Answer (score -1):

1) Можно генерировать SQL запросы(php) на создание у записи полей изменяя их свойства - это сложно.

2) А можно сделать проще структуру сделай такой

id | from | to | text | date | room

через запятую в таблицу заносить данные кто написал и кому, сделать регулярку в php которая будет отсылать указанным через запятую сообщения.

Comment: Так что ли?

    to = '2,3,4,5,6,7'

Comment: такой вариант не подходит

Comment: Нашел еще вот такой способ http://codediscuss.ru/blogs/24-dialogi-mezhdu-polzovatelyami-na-php, но мне не совсем понятно как это будет выглядеть и как осуществляется взаимодействие между таблицами.

Comment: точней не регулярку, а implode(). так же можно хранить в json или serialize

Comment: да вы все серьезно что ли?